# Difference between partition_id and partition_number

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

Can anyone elaborate the difference between *partition_number* and *partition_id* in [sys.partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partitions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (Transact-SQL) , SQL server? Why do we need two different IDs if one could have worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partitions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you link with added emphasis

> partition_id: Indicates the partition ID. Is unique **within a database**.

> partition_number: Is a 1-based partition number **within the owning index or heap**. For non-partitioned tables and indexes, the value of this column is 1.

`partition_id` is the id of the partition within the database. The `partition_number` is for the object it is on, as a table can have multiple partitions, and a database can have multiple partitioned tables.

Answer (score 1):

*partition_id* is unique to the database, similar to a PK for a table.  *partition_number* is the value within a partitioned table or index, since tables (if partitioned) would have more than 1 partition

If you look at [this article](https://www.sqlshack.com/database-table-partitioning-sql-server/), you'll see an example of how the dates in the table have different *partition_numbers*.

[image]

To see the partition_id in use, see [this article](https://simonlearningsqlserver.wordpress.com/tag/sys-partitions/), which shows a query against a partitioned table / index within a database.

[image]

from the following queries, also taken from the article:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.partitions
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.HeapTest');

SELECT *
FROM sys.partitions
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ClusteredIndexTest');
```